# How the Nernst equation is applied for electrodeposition?

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry, reduction-potential, nernst-equation

For using the Nernst equation

$$E = E_0 - \frac{RT}{nF}\ln\frac{[\ce{Red}]}{[\ce{Ox}]}$$

the concentrations of $\ce{Red}$ and $\ce{Ox}$ species are required. For the reaction

$$\ce{Cu+ + e- <=> Cu}$$

in which the $\ce{Red}$ part leaves the solution and has no concentration in the electrolyte. How is the Nernst equation used to calculate the potential at different stages when the reaction proceeds?

Answer (score 1):

For a metal electrode immersed in a solution of its own salt, the concentration of the reduced form as a solid phase remains constant ($[\ce{M^0}] = \mathrm{const}$), therefore:

$$E = E_0 + \frac{RT}{nF}\ln[\ce{Ox}]$$